# jQuery flexslider not displaying first image in slideshow on Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, flexslider

I am working with jQuery flexslider v2.2.2 and am having trouble getting it to behave the way I want.  The user will navigate between different variations of the same product and each time a user clicks on a variation, an ajax call is made to the server to fetch the images.  The code is as follows

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: requestUrl,
  success: function(color) {
    var slider = $('.slider').data('flexslider')
    color.imagesArr.forEach(function(ele, i){
      slider.addSlide("<li><img src="+ele.src" +/></li>")
      slider.flexslider(0);
    })
  }         
})
```

The last image in the image array is the one that always displays regardless of what I do.  Any insight into working with the library would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!